Question about the ‎reciprocal ‎Randic ‎index
$\DeclareMathOperator\RR{RR}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Definitions:

The complement of a graph $G$ is a graph $G^{\prime}$ on the same set of vertices as of $G$ such that there will be an edge between two vertices $(v,e)$ in $G^{\prime}$, if and only if there is no edge in between $(v,e)$ in $G$.

The reciprocal Randic index defined as


$$\RR(G)=\sum_{uv\in E(G)}\sqrt{d_u d_v}.$$

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite simple graph. The Sombor index $\SO(G)$ of $G$ is defined as

$$\SO(G)=\sum_{uv\in E(G)}\sqrt{d_u^{2}+d_v^{2}},\quad\text{where $d_u$ is the degree of vertex $u$ in $G$.}$$
Note: For every edge $uv\in E(G)$ the inequality $ (d_u -d_v)^{2}\geq 0$ holds, then $\SO(G)\geq\sqrt{2}\RR(G)$.
Questions:

Is it right to say $\SO(G^{\prime})\geq\sqrt{2}\RR(G^{\prime})$?

What is the upper or lower bound of  $\SO(G)+ \SO(G^{\prime})$?



Probably unintentionally, your code had lots of invisible occurrences of left-to-right marks, and a few right-to-left marks, that were making it render weirdly.  I removed them, and did some minor TeX clean-up while I was there. \ What does your question (2) mean?

What is the upper or lower bound of $SO(G)+SO(G′)$?
